# Is it okay to set properties on a readonly object in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a `readonly` object property:

```
@property (readonly) MyCustomController* customController;
```

`MyCustomerController` has a property called `myCustomProperty`

Is it okay to set the property on the `readonly` object?

```
self.customController.myCustomProperty = [CustomProperty new];
```

The compiler isn't complaining, and at runtime functionality seems to be fine-- it just seems a little weird that I can set properties on a `readonly` object?
Though technically I guess I am "reading" the property, and then setting a property on it, so I'm technically not setting the actual `readonly` property pointer.

Is it bad practice to do this?  Could anything go wrong?

According to [Rypress](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties):

> The readonly attribute is an easy way to make a property read-only. It
>   omits the setter method and prevents assignment via dot-notation, but
>   the getter is unaffected. As an example, let’s change our Car
>   interface to the following. Notice how you can specify multiple
>   attributes by separating them with a comma.

So it seems like it isn't an issue, I just wanted to double check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Though technically I guess I am "reading" the property, and then setting a property on it, so I'm technically not setting the actual readonly property pointer.

Exactly. It is not the object that is read-only, but your property which stores a reference to the object. You cannot change which object the property references, but you can call methods and properties on that object which alter its state.

What you are doing is perfectly correct and normal.

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful to remember that "dot syntax" for property access is simply syntactic sugar for calling accessor methods. So, your statement:

```
self.customController.myCustomProperty = [CustomProperty new];
```

is (assuming the accessor names haven't been customized) literally equivalent to:

```
[[self customController] setMyCustomProperty:[CustomProperty new]];
```

Note that you're only calling the getter for the `customController` property. That's all the `readonly` attribute means for a property: there's a getter but no setter. Calling the getter is, of course, perfectly fine. Other than by declaring its type, the property has no influence over what you do with the retrieved value.

In either form, you could decompose it into two separate steps:

```
MyCustomController* controller = self.customController;
controller.myCustomProperty = [CustomProperty new];
```

Note that the `customController` property is only involved in the first of those lines. The second is only influenced by the fact that `controller` is of type `MyCustomController*` and the (not shown) declaration of `myCustomProperty`.

Think of another case:

```
// Some method on some class:
- (void) doStuffWithCustomController:(MyCustomController*)controller;

// Your code, in a completely different class:
[foo doStuffWithCustomController:self.controller];
```

Surely, you recognize that `-doStuffWithCustomController:` can do to the `controller` parameter it receives anything that's valid for a `MyCustomController` reference and it doesn't matter where that reference came from. Right? So, it could assign to `controller.myCustomProperty` without concern. Well, so can you.